# Laravel - redirect to second to last url

Tags: php, redirect, laravel, laravel-4, overlay

is it somehow possible to redirect a user, after the auth, to the second to last page?

Why?
I open the Login in an overlay. When the validation throws an error, the Redirect is:

```
return Redirect::intended('?openOverlay=login')->with('error-login-noconfirm','1');
```

When the user enters the right logindata, the Redirect is back(), which means, he will be redirected to the right page BUT with the open Overlay.

I need to get rid of the overlay when the user logs in successfully, means, I maybe need to pass the route to the login method, or something like that.

Do you have an idea? Thanks!

EDIT:
Login code:

```
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::intended('?openOverlay=login')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    } else {
        $user = User::where('email', Input::get('email'))->first();

        if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password'), 'confirmed' => 1))) {
            return Redirect::intended();
        } else {
            return Redirect::intended('?openOverlay=login')->with('error-login-noconfirm','1');
        }
    }
```

intended isn't working too. It redirects me to my / pages instead of the "last" page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use back(). Login process works this way:

1) A 'still not logged' user try to browse your site and hit a route:

```
Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@dashboard');
```

2) But is redirected to the login form:

```
return Redirect::to('?openOverlay=login');
```

3) After a successful login you have to use `Redirect::intended()` to redirect your user to the url he/she first tried to access:

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password)))
{
    // Login succeeded, redirect it to the intended url

    return Redirect::intended('home');
}
else
{
    /// Login failed, redirect back to login, so your user can try to login again

    return Redirect::back()->with('error-login-noconfirm','1');
}
```

Your user will be redirected to 'dashboard' and the 'home' is a fallback route, just in case something happened to the session and there is no more intended ('dashboard') url on it.

If the intended url is not the first one accessed, you can change it in Session:

```
$path = Session::put('url.intended', $the_actual_url_intended);
```

Comment: I tried intended but I redirected me to my / pages instead of, in example, my recipe/details/1 page. See code in my edit... (in a few seconds)

Comment: in my case, intended doesn't know, what my last page is... it redirects me to the /

Comment: Oh, I think I've got it now. You can change the url intended, to the last one, in your session. Take a look at my edit.

Comment: That's nice, I will try it out. See in my code the complete login code... with validation. I think this is also a point if something fails!

Comment: the main problem is, that I open the overlay on the page with JS... but, if an error happens, I need to add ?openOverlay to my url to reopen the overlay in case of an error.

Comment: It's okay, but where is your first redirect to login? Is it an 'auth' filter? It's in that code you may need to change the intended url.

Comment: you mean the route? Route::get('login', array('uses' => 'UserController@showLogin'));

Comment: if not, I open the login form in an overlay, there is no "login" page at all.

Comment: Not the route. How do you know your user is not logged in and you have to redirect it to a some page with the overlay so it logs in? You may have to add the `Session::put('url.intended'...)` in this code, so  Laravel can redirect your user correctly after the login.

Comment: I will check that. s I said, there is just an overlay, after the login, the header changes, nothing more happens. But ok. I will check the url.intended. Thanks!